# How to Make Bootstrap 3 .thumbnail Full With in Large Screens?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5676/) and let me know how I can have horizontal thumbnail in Bootstrap 3 in Large Screens like this image

[image]

As you can see in the left side I have regular Thumbnail and I would like to change it to Full Width Horizontal on large screens and normal Thumbnail  in tables and smart phones

I already tried this

```
.thumbnail.right-caption > img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 9px;
}

.thumbnail.right-caption {
    float: left;
}

.thumbnail.right-caption > .caption {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

but it is not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to follow the format similar to:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <img src="http://pizzafactorytricity.ca/home/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/3-pizza4-300x282.jpg" alt="..."/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
            <div class="caption">
              <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
              <p>...</p>
              <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5677/)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use combination of `display: table-cell` property and media queries. In theory when you are on desktop thumbnail acts like table (so image and content are next to each other) but when you are on mobile resolution they act as block elements (so one above other).

On HTML side you only need to add wrapper div for image with some class, I called it `.image`.

Rest of the magic happens on CSS side.

```
.image {
  display: table-cell;    
}

.caption {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .image, .caption {
    display: block; 
  }   
}
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5678/)